# How to get other array value if match?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Array 1 output

```
 Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( [ID] => 335 [userid] => 4 [username] => demo [media_id] => 17 ) 
       [1] => Array ( [ID] => 436 [userid] => 4 [username] => demo [media_id] => 18 )
       [2] => Array ( [ID] => 637 [userid] => 4 [username] => demo [media_id] => 19 ) 
       [3] => Array ( [ID] => 838 [userid] => 4 [username] => demo [media_id] => 20 ) 
 );
```

Array 2 output

```
 Array ( 
        [1] => Array ( [ID] => 35 [userid] => 4  [media_id] => 17 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [ID] => 36 [userid] => 4  [media_id] => 18 )
     );
```

How to get other array value if match? I need if `media_id` and `userid` of `array 2` match in `array 1` then how to get perticuler `ID` and `username` from `array 1` in foreach loop of `array 2` ?

**Update**

```
$array1 = array ( 
    0 => array ( "ID" => "335", "userid" => "4", "username" => "demo", "media_id" => "17" ), 
    1 => array ( "ID" => "436", "userid" => "4", "username" => "demo", "media_id" => "18" ),
    2 => array ( "ID" => "637", "userid" => "4", "username" => "demo", "media_id" => "19" ), 
    3 => array ( "ID" => "838", "userid" => "4", "username" => "demo", "media_id" => "20" ) 
                      );

$array2 = array ( 
    1 => array ( "ID" => "35", "userid" => "4", "media_id" => "17" ),
    2 => array ( "ID" => "36", "userid" => "4", "media_id" => "18" )
                          );


      foreach($array2 as $array) {

          foreach($array1 as $get_data) {
                 if($array1['media_id'] == $get_data['media_id'] && $array1['userid'] == $get_data['userid']){
                                    $get_result[] = //get_data true;
                                   } else {
                                    $get_result[] = //get_data false;
                                   }
                                }


                      //get ID and username or show false value 


              }
```

**Final answer**

```
foreach($array2 as $array) {
     $return = "false";
     foreach($array1 as $get_data) {
         if($array1['media_id'] == $get_data['media_id'] && $array1['userid'] == $get_data['userid']) {
         $get_result[] = ['ID' => $get_data['ID'], 'username' => $get_data['username']];
         $return = "true";
    }
  }

   if($return = "false"){
        echo false;
   }

}
```

Comment: please put a valid php array, not the output

Comment: Where is your attempt at a `foreach()`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question (I'm not sure), this should work:

```
foreach($array2 as $array) {
  foreach($array1 as $get_data) {
    if($array1['media_id'] == $get_data['media_id'] && $array1['userid'] == $get_data['userid']) {
      $get_result[] = ['ID' => $get_data['ID'], 'username' => $get_data['username']];
    }
  }
}
if (count($get_result) == 0) {
  $get_result[] = false;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and thanks but the problem is, i need a value if false. But it showing multiple false value. I think you understand. @gmc

Comment: Any option to get false only once if not match? I am getting multiple false value.

Comment: I need this in 1st foreach. any idea?

Comment: Thanks for helping but finally i solved it. Check answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your real needs, but @gmc gave you (part of ? all ?) what you need IMHO

```
<?php

$array1 = array ( 
0 => array ( "ID" => "335", "userid" => "4", "username" => "demo", "media_id" => "117" ), 
1 => array ( "ID" => "436", "userid" => "4", "username" => "demo", "media_id" => "118" ),
2 => array ( "ID" => "637", "userid" => "4", "username" => "demo", "media_id" => "19" ), 
3 => array ( "ID" => "838", "userid" => "4", "username" => "demo", "media_id" => "20" ) 
                  );

$array2 = array ( 
1 => array ( "ID" => "35", "userid" => "4", "media_id" => "17" ),
2 => array ( "ID" => "36", "userid" => "4", "media_id" => "18" )
                      );

$get_result = array();

  foreach($array2 as $array) {

      foreach($array1 as $get_data) {
             if( ($array['media_id'] == $get_data['media_id']) && ($array['userid'] == $get_data['userid'])) {
                                $get_result[] = ['ID' => $get_data['ID'], 'username' => $get_data['username']];
                               }
                            }
  }

if (count($get_result) == 0) {
echo"false";
}
else {
echo"true"; print_r($get_result); }
?>

/* I modified values to 117 & 118 -> returns "false" */
/* If you set values to 17 & 18 -> returns "true" */
```

Comment: Working but the problem is same i need a value `false` only once in else option but i getting multiple time.

Comment: -> i need a value false -> what do you mean ? "media_id" => "17" -> true + "media_id" => "18" -> true + "media_id" => "19" -> false + "media_id" => "20" -> false ? but where do you need to store the false answers ?

Comment: see gmc answer. I think he perfectly understand my question

Comment: I need this in 1st foreach.

Comment: Thanks for helping but finally i solved it. Check answer.